# XML Schema, Error resolving component

Tags: xml, schema

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Employees">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="secondName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dateOfBirth" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="role" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<!-- only allowing two genders -->
<xs:simpleType name="gender">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="F"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!--restrict the job types allowed to be entered-->
<xs:simpleType name="roleType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Manager"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Assistant Manager"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Lifeguard"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Rececptionist"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Gym Instructor"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is my code for my XML Schema and whenever I change the type of "role" to "roleType" I get an error saying the following

```
ERROR - src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:roleType'. It was detected that 'xs:roleType' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
```

Any help or advice appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you didn't change the type of `role` to `roleType`, you changed it to `xs:roleType`, which is clearly wrong, because `roleType` is not in the XML Schema namespace.